# On what interval is $f(x)=x-\tan(x)$ increasing or decreasing?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My attempt at the solution is:
$$
f'(x) = 1- \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} $$
We check when $f'(x)=0$ to determine when the derivative is zero.
$$
1- \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} = 0 \iff 1 = \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} \iff \cos^2(x)=1
$$
From that we can see that
$$
x=n\pi, n \in \mathbb Z.
$$
I don't understand how to continue. Normally we use a "signs table" in this situation when the given function is a regular one and not trigonometric.

Comment: Hint: $\cos^2(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Not sure if I understood this correctly, does all $x <= 1$ mean that it is decreasing everywhere where it is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is defined over the intervals of the form $(-\pi/2+k\pi,\pi/2+k\pi)$, for $k$ any integer.

For simplicity, let $a_k=-\pi/2+k\pi$ and $b_k=\pi/2+k\pi$. From the known behavior of the tangent function, we can see that
$$
\lim_{x\downarrow{a_k}}(x-\tan x)=\infty,\qquad
\lim_{x\uparrow{b_k}}(x-\tan x)=-\infty
$$
(limit from the right and from the left, respectively).

The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=1-(1+\tan^2x)=-\tan^2x
$$
which is everywhere negative, except at the points $k\pi$, so it just vanishes once in each interval $(a_k,b_k)$. Due to this, the function is strictly decreasing over each interval $(a_k,b_k)$.

You can see it from the “table of signs": the derivative is negative over $(a_k,k\pi)$ and also over $(k\pi,b_k)$, so the function is strictly decreasing over $(a_k,k\pi]$ and also over $[k\pi,b_k)$, hence strictly decreasing in the whole interval.

Beware, though, that you *cannot* state that the function is everywhere decreasing, because it obviously isn't.

[image]

Note that the second derivative is $f''(x)=-2\tan x(1+\tan^2x)$, so the points where the derivative vanish are inflection points.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's better to work with the inequality directly.  $f$ is increasing if $f' > 0$.  So we require $$1 - \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} > 0,$$ or $$\cos^2 x - 1 > 0, \quad \cos x \ne 0.$$  But because $-1 \le \cos x \le 1$, we have $\cos^2 x \le 1$, hence this inequality is never satisfied, and $f$ is never strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Let the derivative of your function: $f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}}=\frac{\cos^2{x}-1}{\cos^2{x}}\leq 0$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, since $\cos^2{x}\leq 1$. So the function is always decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

In the intervalle $ I_k= (\frac{-\pi}{2}+2k\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi) $,
$ f $ is continuous,
$$f'(x)=1-1-\tan^2(x)\le 0$$
and
$$f'(x)=0\iff x=2k\pi$$
So, $ f $ is Strictly decreasing at $ I_k$.

The same at $ J_k=(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi)$.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the motivation behind making $1−1−tan2()$ less than or equal zero? Is it due to making an assumption about the function decreasing?

Comment: @ErikMartinesSanches $1-1-(\tan{x})^2=-(\tan{x})^2\leq 0$. The square of something is always non negative.

Comment: @ErikMartinesSanches Yes and the second condition makes it strictly decreasing.